# Tomcat stopped without any log or any stack

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, virtual-machine

We have trouble with Tomcat 5.5 which stops at night on our production servers (Linux CentOS 4.8) and we have no idea why it stops...
There is no Tomcat's log in catalina.out or any application's log.

We tried different things to find why the server stops:

- configure Tomcat to be able to generate a core dump
- instrument `System.exit()` method with javassist to find if the method was called
- add a shutdown hook to the JVM (with `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`)

None of them worked, we have no core dump, the Exit method and the shutdown hook are not called.
My conclusions are:

- The VM is not terminated properly but crash without any log.

Any idea or log to read to find why Tomcat stops?

Comment: If you can replicate this problem on another server, you can use jConsole to monitor your JVM

Comment: I've seen Tomcat stopping on me while running it from Eclipse. The stop didn't manifest any sort of messages or logs either, however I think I narrowed it down to stack overflow issues during recursive fetches by Hibernate.

Comment: We cannot replicate the problem, it occurs sometimes on different servers which are not doing anything specific.

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing the issue ?

Answer (score 25):

1. Make sure you know where `stderr` is redirected and check if anything got printed there.
2. Check the memory limits on Tomcat and how much free memory does the system have.  Review the Linux system logs under `/var/log` to see if anything suspicious happened during the time.  For example, kernel can randomly kill a process (almost) without a trace if the system is running low on memory.

We've ran 5.5 in production for years and never had any unexplained shutdowns, FWIW.

Comment: Bingo. /var/log/message has "Out of memory: Kill process 31201 (java) score 783 or sacrifice child".

Comment: +1. as suggested by KOF: `/var/log/messages` was showing that java process got killed.

Comment: Use `dmesg` command if you don't have access to `/var/log/messages`

Comment: /var/log/kern.log in my case

Comment: Me as well @PbxMan, on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

As suggested here in other answers checked system logs in `/var/log/messages` but permission denied for me. So, I used `dmesg` command instead and got this in the logs

"Out of memory: Kill process 14606 (java) score 106 or sacrifice child".

In the output I also noticed **Swap Memory free 0 K**. Ran `top` command to confirm the same. So, somehow there was a high memory usage which caused the OS to kill my tomcat process.

After spending hours finally got the reason.

`ps -ef | grep tomcat` showed that there were several tomcat processes running for the same application. It seems that, earlier tomcat shutdowns might not have been completed successfully and due to some reason the processes were not killed even after the shutdown, which was causing the high memory usage.

So, killed all running tomcat processes using `kill`. SWAP memory got freed.

Started tomcat again, worked fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is a stack-overflow exception. This is typical behavior of Tomcat when it happens. For example, you're trying to serialize to JSON or XML beans with cyclic dependencies (but without handling of the cycles).

Everytime I had this issue (several times) it always has been this one. All other stops are usually logged properly (like OutOfMemory etc).

This type of stops leaves no trace anywhere.

Comment: Everytime I had this issue (several times) it always has been this one. All other stops are usually logged properly (like OutOfMemory etc).

Comment: is there any way you know to debug/highlight this somehow @Eugene Retunsky? How can you verify that claim?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 7 has an option inside catalina to prevent the System.exit class call or something similar: http://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat7/docs/security-manager-howto.html .

Maybe there's a similar option for the 5.5 version. Try the documentation.

There are options to redirect the output to the same console that you use to start Tomcat. This information is redirected to logs when you execute on Unix based systems, on Windows, it remains with the console if not redirected.