# Tomcat process crashed without any logs

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running Tomcat with root privilege, and there's a url that whenever I visit, it caused the Tomcat process terminated without any logs in catalina.log. It turns out there's a dead loop in my application. But my assumption is that a dead loop(actually a infinite recursion) in handling a request could only lead to a stackoverflow Exception that might terminate the current thread being created by Tomcat.

My question is, is this possible that a dead loop of application caused the whole Tomcat crushed? If so, how can I observe the error log?

Sorry I didn't point it out actually it is a infinite recursion in my code, I have debugged it a lot under Eclipse, and it is the recursion that never exit halt the request but I only got a StackOverflowError after waiting for a long time, however I was wondering why tomcat crashed?

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you running, and on what platform?

Comment: But will Tomcat exit without any logs, I didn't find any in catalina.out or in other logs. BTW the version 5.5.31.

Comment: If Tomcat crashed, especially if the crash was because it ran out of stack space, there's really no telling what problems could occur. Perhaps it didn't flush logs, or the logging facilities encountered errors due to low stack space.

Comment: The author of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10300943/616460 also observes that Tomcat crashes due to stack errors generally leave no logs. It may have left an *hs_err_pid.log* file somewhere if the JVM crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to be more specific and show some relevant code. However, a couple of thoughts:

- An unbounded loop alone would not cause a [`StackOverflowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html). It would just halt indefinitely. That exception is generally caused by running out of stack space due to deep recursion, which is not how you describe your code.
- It sounds like you have a hunch about where the offending code is. In that case, you should probably add some log messages yourself to get more information. See the following resources for information about logging in Tomcat:

  - [Tomcat Logging Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html)
  - [Redirect stderr/stdout in Tomcat](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/knowledge-base/how-redirect-stderr-and-stdout-messages)
  - [Notes about running as service vs. application on Windows](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Where-does-my-stderr-go-td1994265.html) (presuming Windows).
- You may also wish to consider running your service in a debugger (e.g. Eclipse has a web application debugger, as do many IDEs) and/or testing your code outside of Tomcat.

You will have to post more detailed information if you want a more specific answer.

---

Update regarding your edit:

Tomcat runs all web applications in a single JVM (and it runs in that JVM as well), just with different class loaders. This means all applications share the same stack space, so it's conceivably possible that if one app eats too much stack space, other apps and Tomcat itself will start running into issues as well -- possibly encountering their own stack overflow errors. That's as specific as I can get without seeing any code.

If you have one application that has a risk of misbehaving, it is possible to run multiple Tomcat instances (i.e. separate JVMs) so that problems in that application do not affect the others. See the file *RUNNING.TXT*, included with your Tomcat distribution, for information about running multiple instances and integrating them together.

Obviously, however, the best approach is to fix the problem in your code. :)

Comment: @夜神ライト I've updated the answer with a little more (hopefully helpful) info and a note about running a separate Tomcat instance for the misbehaving app.

Comment: Hello, I searched every folds under $JAVA_HOME and $TOMCAT_HOME but still unable to locate the hs_err_pid.log file. Should I add some settings in running Tomcat?

Comment: Well, if you can upgrade to Tomcat 6.x, you could try making sure log buffering is disabled, as per http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html (see juli configuration, or whatever logger you are using). AFAIK Tomcat 5.5 doesn't have buffering control options, at least not with juli. But really you should fix the errors in your code (an easy test is to disable that portion of the code -- you say you saw the errors in your debugger, you should attempt to correct them there).