# Tomcat 7 crashes automatically

Tags: tomcat, crash, jvm, tomcat7, jvm-crash

Apache Tomcat 7 shuts down without writing any error or exception in logs .

With referring to [Tomcat shuts down automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003738/tomcat-shuts-down-automatically) thread I got hs_err_pid10192.log file in work directory.

Please explain what is the exact error?

hs_err_pid10192.log

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x06151ad9, pid=10192, tid=8772

JRE version: 6.0_21-b07
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [AspriseOCR.dll+0x31ad9]

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
 http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x033d0800):  JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8772, stack(0x03890000,0x03900000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x3b31b044

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x038f8dec, EDX=0x3b31c000
ESP=0x038f8d98, EBP=0x00000000, ESI=0x3b2e7f20, EDI=0x3b31b028
EIP=0x06151ad9, EFLAGS=0x00010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x038f8d98)
0x038f8d98:   038f8df0 038ff108 374f3c20 038f8dec
0x038f8da8:   061523b5 038f8df0 033d0800 038f8dec
0x038f8db8:   038ff108 374f3c48 06126bf6 038f8dec
0x038f8dc8:   038f8dec 00000006 038feeb8 038f8dec
0x038f8dd8:   062c0a40 062c0a54 00000004 00000002
0x038f8de8:   033d0918 038feed0 404d2028 00000352
0x038f8df8:   0000012c 00000001 00000000 00000000
0x038f8e08:   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x06151ad9)
0x06151ac9:   ff 57 e8 40 51 0a 00 83 c4 0c 8b 0d c0 1f 2c 06
0x06151ad9:   0f b7 47 1c 66 3d 60 00 74 06 66 3d 27 00 75 41 


Stack: [0x03890000,0x03900000],  sp=0x038f8d98,  free space=1a3038f88d4k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [AspriseOCR.dll+0x31ad9]

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.performOCR(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;I)Ljava/lang/String;
J  com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR.processString(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
J  com.mindcraft.scu.servlets.OCR_Processor.processor(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)Ljava/lang/String;
J  com.mindcraft.scu.servlets.OCR_Processor.doGet(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
J  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
J  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Request;Lorg/apache/catalina/connector/Response;)V
J  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Lorg/apache/coyote/Request;Lorg/apache/coyote/Response;)V
J  org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;
J  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketWrapper;Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/SocketStatus;)Lorg/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint$Handler$SocketState;
J  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run()V
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V
J  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00b57c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8584, stack(0x38ac0000,0x38b30000)]
  0x03459800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8828, stack(0x38a50000,0x38ac0000)]
  0x03b32800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8580, stack(0x389e0000,0x38a50000)]
  0x035fd400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8328, stack(0x38970000,0x389e0000)]
  0x033cbc00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5952, stack(0x38900000,0x38970000)]
  0x033afc00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3668, stack(0x03900000,0x03970000)]
=>0x033d0800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=8772, stack(0x03890000,0x03900000)]
  0x034c6800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8520, stack(0x38890000,0x38900000)]
  0x03a81400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9384, stack(0x060b0000,0x06120000)]
  0x034f0400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2696, stack(0x05db0000,0x05e20000)]
  0x034a9800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-exec-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10152, stack(0x05d40000,0x05db0000)]
  0x03567c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4932, stack(0x05cd0000,0x05d40000)]
  0x03537800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=988, stack(0x05c60000,0x05cd0000)]
  0x03a42000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5620, stack(0x05bf0000,0x05c60000)]
  0x03a40c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8444, stack(0x05b80000,0x05bf0000)]
  0x0352e000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5636, stack(0x05b10000,0x05b80000)]
  0x0352c800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2360, stack(0x05aa0000,0x05b10000)]
  0x03b19000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8500, stack(0x05a30000,0x05aa0000)]
  0x03b17800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8212, stack(0x059c0000,0x05a30000)]
  0x03556400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3568, stack(0x05950000,0x059c0000)]
  0x03531000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8408, stack(0x058e0000,0x05950000)]
  0x0357e800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8416, stack(0x05870000,0x058e0000)]
  0x0357d000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3616, stack(0x05800000,0x05870000)]
  0x0357a000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6400, stack(0x05790000,0x05800000)]
  0x03578c00 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9572, stack(0x05320000,0x05390000)]
  0x034f2400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8240, stack(0x052b0000,0x05320000)]
  0x03b20000 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9988, stack(0x05240000,0x052b0000)]
  0x03514800 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9392, stack(0x051d0000,0x05240000)]
  0x03513400 JavaThread "ajp-apr-8119-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5612, stack(0x05160000,0x051d0000)]
  0x0351d000 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-AsyncTimeout" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7144, stack(0x050f0000,0x05160000)]
  0x0351f400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9092, stack(0x05080000,0x050f0000)]
  0x03572000 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Sendfile-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1268, stack(0x05010000,0x05080000)]
  0x03546c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9488, stack(0x04fa0000,0x05010000)]
  0x03ab7c00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5556, stack(0x04f30000,0x04fa0000)]
  0x0356a400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8544, stack(0x04ec0000,0x04f30000)]
  0x03518400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10204, stack(0x04e50000,0x04ec0000)]
  0x03548000 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2812, stack(0x04de0000,0x04e50000)]
  0x039e3800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7276, stack(0x04d70000,0x04de0000)]
  0x03b30400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4784, stack(0x04d00000,0x04d70000)]
  0x03574400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-CometPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10128, stack(0x04c90000,0x04d00000)]
  0x03add400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8928, stack(0x04c20000,0x04c90000)]
  0x03b05400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4848, stack(0x04bb0000,0x04c20000)]
  0x03b16800 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6492, stack(0x04940000,0x049b0000)]
  0x0353c000 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9792, stack(0x048d0000,0x04940000)]
  0x03528400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8596, stack(0x04860000,0x048d0000)]
  0x03a8fc00 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3520, stack(0x047f0000,0x04860000)]
  0x035c8400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2324, stack(0x04780000,0x047f0000)]
  0x03522400 JavaThread "http-apr-8090-Poller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5368, stack(0x04710000,0x04780000)]
  0x03a1dc00 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7820, stack(0x046a0000,0x04710000)]
  0x03b12400 JavaThread "scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=8404, stack(0x04620000,0x04690000)]
  0x03b1a400 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=9080, stack(0x045b0000,0x04620000)]
  0x03b0c000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=3864, stack(0x04540000,0x045b0000)]
  0x03afa800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=5632, stack(0x044d0000,0x04540000)]
  0x03af9000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=10052, stack(0x04460000,0x044d0000)]
  0x03b0a800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3480, stack(0x043f0000,0x04460000)]
  0x03b09000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=8340, stack(0x04380000,0x043f0000)]
  0x03b07800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=6704, stack(0x04310000,0x04380000)]
  0x03b06400 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=10184, stack(0x042a0000,0x04310000)]
  0x03ae6400 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=8432, stack(0x04230000,0x042a0000)]
  0x03aec000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4084, stack(0x041c0000,0x04230000)]
  0x033f8400 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9812, stack(0x037e0000,0x03850000)]
  0x00b3d400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6280, stack(0x02f20000,0x02f90000)]
  0x00b37000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9148, stack(0x02eb0000,0x02f20000)]
  0x00b35800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9880, stack(0x02e40000,0x02eb0000)]
  0x00b34400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10068, stack(0x02dd0000,0x02e40000)]
  0x00b2d400 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8344, stack(0x02d60000,0x02dd0000)]
  0x00b2bc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9324, stack(0x00c80000,0x00cf0000)]
  0x006f7000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9340, stack(0x00700000,0x00770000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00b2a800 VMThread [stack: 0x00c10000,0x00c80000] [id=9140]
  0x00b48000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02f90000,0x03000000] [id=9972]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 157248K, used 56593K [0x06990000, 0x11430000, 0x11430000)
  eden space 139776K,  40% used [0x06990000, 0x0a09d098, 0x0f210000)
  from space 17472K,   1% used [0x10320000, 0x103574f0, 0x11430000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x0f210000, 0x0f210000, 0x10320000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 8840K [0x11430000, 0x26990000, 0x26990000)
   the space 349568K,   2% used [0x11430000, 0x11cd20a0, 0x11cd2200, 0x26990000)
 compacting perm gen  total 14080K, used 13886K [0x26990000, 0x27750000, 0x36990000)
   the space 14080K,  98% used [0x26990000, 0x2771faa0, 0x2771fc00, 0x27750000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x36990000, 0x36ebb700, 0x36ebb800, 0x37390000)
    rw space 12288K,  54% used [0x37390000, 0x37a276c0, 0x37a27800, 0x37f90000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00417000     C:\Tomcat7_OCR\bin\Tomcat7_OCR.exe
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8c2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x77e40000 - 0x77f42000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x7d1e0000 - 0x7d27c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77c50000 - 0x77cef000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x76f50000 - 0x76f63000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7c8d0000 - 0x7d0cf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x77ba0000 - 0x77bfa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c49000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77380000 - 0x77411000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77da0000 - 0x77df2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x77420000 - 0x77523000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.3959_x-ww_D8713E55\comctl32.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6daa7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76aa0000 - 0x76acd000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x71bc0000 - 0x71bc8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rdpsnd.dll
0x771f0000 - 0x77201000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x71c40000 - 0x71c97000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x76b70000 - 0x76b7b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d560000 - 0x6d569000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x03600000 - 0x036d9000     C:\Tomcat7_OCR\bin\tcnative-1.dll
0x71c00000 - 0x71c17000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71bf0000 - 0x71bf8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71b20000 - 0x71b61000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSWSOCK.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68035000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x6d790000 - 0x6d798000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x761b0000 - 0x76243000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x76190000 - 0x761a2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x5f270000 - 0x5f2ca000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71ae0000 - 0x71ae8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x76ed0000 - 0x76efa000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76f70000 - 0x76f77000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f10000 - 0x76f3e000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76f80000 - 0x76f85000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x73070000 - 0x73097000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76290000 - 0x762ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
0x77670000 - 0x777a9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x77530000 - 0x775c7000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.3790.3959_x-ww_78FCF8D0\COMCTL32.dll
0x06120000 - 0x062de000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\AspriseOCR.dll
0x062f0000 - 0x06478000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DevIL.dll
0x06480000 - 0x06494000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ILU.dll
0x762b0000 - 0x762f9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x77d00000 - 0x77d8b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x7fe00000 - 0x7fe31000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEACC.dll
0x064a0000 - 0x06505000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcp60.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Tomcat7_OCR -Dcatalina.base=C:\Tomcat7_OCR -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Tomcat7_OCR\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Tomcat7_OCR\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Tomcat7_OCR\conf\logging.properties -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xms512m -Xmx512m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Tomcat6\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Tomcat6\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors\cmbicmenv.ini;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors\cmbicmsrvs.ini;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8;C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin
PATH=.;C:\Program Files\HP\NCU;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre6\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\Client\;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors\cmbicmenv.ini;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\db2cmv8\cmgmt\connectors\cmbicmsrvs.ini;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\java\db2java.zip;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\Client\;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\inso;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\db2cmv8\dll;C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2003 family Build 3790 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 4 (32 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 44 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 6290696k(2469004k free), swap 10299332k(3269856k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (17.0-b17) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_21-b07), built on Jul 17 2010 01:10:15 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Sat May 04 10:08:13 2013
elapsed time: 69299 seconds**
```

Comment: Are you running a 64-Bit Tomcat on a 32-bit java vm?

Comment: @stacker how to check this?

Comment: Not sure the version.sh script is still included http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-check-tomcat-version-installed/, `java -version` shows something like Java HotSpot(TM) **64-Bit** Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to run native code in one of your webapps: The error message mentions `AspriseOCR.dll` and if you look into the stacktrace, you can find what kind of code has been called with this DLL (hint: the first 4 lines of the stacktrace).

This code is basically running outside of the sandbox and run into a regular crash in native code. If this happens more often you might want to run this native code outside of your webcontainer and rather interface with it: Whenever that program crashes you can restart it without interrupting webserver activity.