# Tomcat Shutdown automatically without any memory exception

Tags: tomcat, shutdown

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet. The server I use is Apache Tomcat.

If I don't access the application for a long time, the Operating System kills the Tomcat process automatically. I learnt that it could happen due to the idle time of that process. How could I handle this from my application.

Comment: This is unusual - the OS will not kill the app because it is not being used. What are you deploying on - local machine or some server?

Comment: Maybe have useful things at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003738/tomcat-shuts-down-automatically